# how can force custom filter pipe be executed in angular2

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I have a question in custom filtering in angular2 .

This is the my scenario:

My page contains several custom components. One of them is responsible for showing data at the left side of the page: (componentA)

```
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let item of items | filter :  filter | sort:   sort; let i = index"  " >
       <template [render]="itemTemplateRef" [context.item]="item" 
       [context.index]="index"></template>
   </md-list-item>
```

and also ,filter is done by a custom filtering:

```
    import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';



@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(values: any[], filter: any): any {
        if (typeof filter !== "function") return values;
          return values.filter((elem) => {
             return filter(elem);
        });
    }
}
```

In main page ,I send a function as an input attribute into Component A:

```
   public filter = (element: MyBean) => {
             return (element.email !== undefined);

    }
```

at Loading of the page, it's executed without any problems. but I want to change filter condition several times by clicking on a checkbox.
I know this fact that,  pure filtering is executed , if the input value change.
But what I don't know  , which input value in my scenario should be changed to force filtering?

when I add following function in the Onchange event of checkbox,nothing is filtered.(items is bind into my component shown data)

```
    createFilterCondition = (searchCondition: string) => {

        items.filter((element) => {
            return this.doFilter(elem);
        });
    }
   public doFilter= (element: MessagesBean) => {

        return (element.email !== undefined);
    }
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways

Make the pipe impure

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filter', pure: false })
```

The disadvantage is that the pipe will be executed very often (every time change detection is run). You can optimize by caching the result and only do the filtering when one of the parameters has changed but checking whether an array was modified isn't too cheap either.

Another way is to pass an additional param to the pipe. If the value or a parameter for a pipe changed, Angular executes the pipe again

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(values: any[], filter: any, changeIndicator: number): any {
        if (typeof filter !== "function") return values;
          return values.filter((elem) => {
             return filter(elem);
        });
    }
}
```

Not you just have to increment `changeIndicator` in your component to make Angular execute the pipe again at the next change detection run.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for response.
It is solved by creating a new array. If this is not a good way for filtering, please inform me.

Following I describe what I did:

I handled it by creating another array instead of original one.(named filteredArray)

and keep the result of filter on it, consequently , bind filterArray into my  component. I realised that filter method on arrays returns a new array. so put the the result in new variable:

```
 this.filteredArray = this.records.filter((element) => {
            return this.filterSms(element);
        }); 

public filterSms = (element: MessagesBean) => {
          return (element.mobile !== undefined);
}
```

Comment: That's a common workaround. If it's good or bad mostly depends on how expensive it is to create a copy of the array. If it has <100 items and doesn't change too often it's probably ok. If there are a few thousands of items then my approach would probably be much more efficient.